# open new page when user select radio button and then click button in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i am creating 3 radio buttons and one button in one page which is in one frame...

when i select 1st radio button and click ok button i want to open jsp page on 2nd frame...

```
<frameset rows="60%,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="header.jsp" name="frame1" scrolling="no" noresize >
<frame src="center.jsp" name="frame2" >
</frameset>
```

in header.jsp radio buttons and ok button had made...so tell me how can i made function on button click...??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in the onclick sentence of your button:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Reload 2nd frame"
    onclick="window.parent.frames['frame2'].reload();" />
```